# Problems when drawing images in java applets

Tags: java, applet

I am new to java and I am creating an applet. I ran into some problems where I cannot draw anything using any of the draw functions. I know my code is not perfect but I would appreciate any help.

This is my code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;

public class CardsJavaProgram extends Applet {

    public void init(){
    this.setBackground( Color.blue );

    }
    public void paint( Graphics screen ){
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int x2 = 10;
    int y2 = 110;
        Image c1 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c1.gif" );
        Image c2 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c2.gif" );
        Image c3 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c3.gif" );
        Image c4 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c4.gif" );
        Image c5 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c5.gif" );
        Image c6 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c6.gif" );
        Image c7 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c7.gif" );
        Image c8 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c8.gif" );
        Image c9 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c9.gif" );
        Image c10 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c10.gif" );
        Image cj = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/cj.gif" );
        Image cq = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/cq.gif" );
        Image ck = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/ck.gif" );
        Image h1 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h1.gif" );
        Image h2 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h2.gif" );
        Image h3 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h3.gif" );
        Image h4 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h4.gif" );
        Image h5 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h5.gif" );
        Image h6 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h6.gif" );
        Image h7 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h7.gif" );
        Image h8 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h8.gif" );
        Image h9 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h9.gif" );
        Image h10 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h10.gif" );
        Image hj = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/hj.gif" );
        Image hq = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/hq.gif" );
        Image hk = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/hk.gif" );
        Image d1 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d1.gif" );
        Image d2 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d2.gif" );
        Image d3 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d3.gif" );
        Image d4 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d4.gif" );
        Image d5 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d5.gif" );
        Image d6 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d6.gif" );
        Image d7 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d7.gif" );
        Image d8 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d8.gif" );
        Image d9 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d9.gif" );
        Image d10 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d10.gif" );
        Image dj = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/dj.gif" );
        Image dq = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/dq.gif" );
        Image dk = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/dk.gif" );
        Image s1 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s1.gif" );
        Image s2 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s2.gif" );
        Image s3 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s3.gif" );
        Image s4 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s4.gif" );
        Image s5 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s5.gif" );
        Image s6 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s6.gif" );
        Image s7 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s7.gif" );
        Image s8 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s8.gif" );
        Image s9 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s9.gif" );
        Image s10 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s10.gif" );
        Image sj = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/sj.gif" );
        Image sq = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/sq.gif" );
        Image sk = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/sk.gif" );

        Image [] cards = new Image [ 52 ];
        cards [ 0 ] = c1;
        cards [ 1 ] = c2;
        cards [ 2 ] = c3;
        cards [ 3 ] = c4;
        cards [ 4 ] = c5;
        cards [ 5 ] = c6;
        cards [ 6 ] = c7;
        cards [ 7 ] = c8;
        cards [ 8 ] = c9;
        cards [ 9 ] = c10;
        cards [ 10 ] = cj;
        cards [ 11 ] = cq;
        cards [ 12 ] = ck;
        cards [ 13 ] = h1;
        cards [ 14 ] = h2;
        cards [ 15 ] = h3;
        cards [ 16 ] = h4;
        cards [ 17 ] = h5;
        cards [ 18 ] = h6;
        cards [ 19 ] = h7;
        cards [ 20 ] = h8;
        cards [ 21 ] = h9;
        cards [ 22 ] = h10;
        cards [ 23 ] = hj;
        cards [ 24 ] = hq;
        cards [ 25 ] = hk;
        cards [ 26 ] = d1;
        cards [ 27 ] = d2;
        cards [ 28 ] = d3;
        cards [ 29 ] = d4;
        cards [ 30 ] = d5;
        cards [ 31 ] = d6;
        cards [ 32 ] = d7;
        cards [ 33 ] = d8;
        cards [ 34 ] = d9;
        cards [ 35 ] = d10;
        cards [ 36 ] = dj;
        cards [ 37 ] = dq;
        cards [ 38 ] = dk;
        cards [ 39 ] = s1;
        cards [ 40 ] = s2;
        cards [ 41 ] = s3;
        cards [ 42 ] = s4;
        cards [ 43 ] = s5;
        cards [ 44 ] = s6;
        cards [ 45 ] = s7;
        cards [ 46 ] = s8;
        cards [ 47 ] = s9;
        cards [ 48 ] = s10;
        cards [ 49 ] = sj;
        cards [ 50 ] = sq;
        cards [ 51 ] = sk;
    screen.drawImage( getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c1.gif" ), 100, 100, this );
    screen.drawImage( getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c1.gif" ), 10, 10, this );
    screen.drawImage( getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c1.gif" ), 50, 50, this );
    screen.drawString( " test ", 10, 10, this );
    /*for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        screen.drawImage (cards[( int ) ( float ) Math.random () * 52 - 1], x, y, this);
        x = x + 5;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        screen.drawImage (cards [( int ) ( float ) ( Math.random () ) * 52 - ( int ) ( 1 )], x2, y2, this);
        x = x + 10;
    }*/
    }





}
```

I created an index and all the files are in the right place.

Comment: Just a thought - instead of hardcoding 104 lines for filling a deck, consider using `for` loops, or better a `Suite` class that fills itself with 13 entries.

Comment: I do not know how to create a loop that changes the name of the variable for each loop and I don't know what a suite class is. please explain thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
Image c1 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c1.gif" );
```

These lines are in the `paint(Graphics)` method.  Never try to do I/O or other time consuming tasks (like loading an a 'deck full' of images) in paint!

The images should be declared as class attributes (declared outside any method) something like this:

```
Image c1;
```

Then loaded in `init()`.

```
c1 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c1.gif" );
```

Comment: Also remember that java.awt.Image is typically unbuffered. That is, it won't load the image data until it's needed. Doing what you are doing will discard the previous load request and start again, resulting in the images never getting a chance to load.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to fix your code to avoid hard coded values.

You're extending the Applet class, which defines a paint method itself, so you must first call the base paint method, with `super.paint(screen)`, also i suggest you to check if you're really loading the images you're getting there.

Also, a very common error with applets is that the classes are not being loaded, so take a look at the Java console to see if you have any loader error, as an advice, you can make this a Frame application and translate it later to Applet.

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the complete code to display the image

Kindly refer through it
/*Arpana*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

/*
<applet code="Img" width=500 height=500>
</applet>
*/

public class Img extends Applet
{
    Image image;
    public void init()
    {
        image=getImage(getCodeBase(),"Appu.jpg");
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)   
    {
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Image picture;  
picture = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"sonoo.jpg");  
g.drawImage(picture, 30,30, this);
```